# setting CPU throttling per user on server 2012

Tags: performance, powershell, window, windows-server

On server 2008 R2 i programatically set the CPU LIMIT to a certain percentage with the following PowerShell

```
function Set-UserAccountCPUThrottle
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
$UserNameToRestrict,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[int]$CpuPercentage = 5
)

write-host "about to restrict user account $UserNameToRestrict to use ${CpuPercentage}% CPU"

  try
    {     
      $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($UserNameToRestrict)
      $local:ResolvedSID= $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value.trim()   
    }
  catch
    {
      throw "Cannot resolve the User (or find its SID) for $UserNameToRestrict"
    }    
 $regpath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Quota System\${local:ResolvedSID}"
 #in creating a new key for this sid, it will remove any old item
mkdir $regpath -Force -ErrorAction stop | out-null
#as the old key if existing was removed by the above code, this will create a new value
 New-ItemProperty -Path $regpath  -Name "CpuRateLimit" -Value $CpuPercentage -PropertyType "DWord" -Force -ErrorAction stop | out-null   

}
```

However while this does create the registry key per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384148(v=ws.10).aspx

it has null effect on server 2012 or windows 8. Is this broken or is there a new way to do this in server 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753280.aspx), resource management is not enforced unless the total CPU usage is greater than 70%.

Is your machine that busy? That page also describes a few other cases where resource management may not occur.

You didn't mention precisely what you are trying to control. If your workload is RDS (virtual desktops, session-based desktops or RemoteApp programs), the Windows Server 2012 "FairShare" feature might be more useful to you. Relevant snippet:

> "Fairshare of resources in RD Session Host.  In Windows Server 2012,
>   RD Session Host server allocates CPU, Disk I/O, and Network I/O such
>   that a single user cannot consume resources that would negatively
>   impact other users on the same host.  Each user will get a “fair
>   share”.  This is done with minimum overhead so the CPU, disk, and
>   network resources are used to maximum capacity."

That snippet can be found about midway down [this technet page.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2012/05/09/windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-services-rds.aspx)

Comment: on server 2008 r2, the above technique does work and does limit it to percentages. we run it on thousands of servers sometimes limiting to 5% and othertimes 15% and it works flawlessly. it just doesn't work with 2012. Thanks for the links though, they may lead me in the right direction

Comment: i'm basing it on a user account with this technique. it is controlling a windows service running under that user, and that service also periodically spawns an executable. that lasts for about 5 minutes and as it is throttling it based on the user, the combination of both of those processes keeps it under x% on server 2008 r2

Comment: looks like that is terminal services related, and not my context. Oh well. Another thing to test this throttling i create a scheduled task running under the user that just runs powershell -command "while($true){}" which on a single core box take that single process over 95%... on server 2012, while on 2008 r2 with this technique it keeps it at 5% or whatever i set.